# How to delete potential malware files in sbin/bin system directory on Mac M1?

Tags: directory, system, malware, kernel-extension

I found two very dubious kexts (kextload and kextutil) by checking my login items on my m1pro macbook. I deactivated them but would still like to know how to delete them for good, since they do not seem to be from apple or a trusted source. I have no idea how they were installed in the first place, but probably by a family member accidentally.

I attached [a screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4WJ81.jpg) showing location and files

Thank you

Tried deleting but you cannot delete in this folder

Comment: This is not a programming question, it's a user question about macOS and should be asked on/moved to https://apple.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Note that "kextload" and "kextutil" are not kexts, they are the built-in tools on macOS for *loading* kexts. I do not recommend you delete them. I'm not sure why they're showing up in your login items however.